# How do I change the block type using the Notion SDK or API?

Tags: notion-api

I'd like to change, for example, an existing block's type from 'paragraph' to 'heading_2' or any of the other blocks mentioned [here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/block). I've tried the [update method](https://developers.notion.com/reference/update-a-block). But it just throws the error, 'Expected block type paragraph in request body' if I try to change the existing block's type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported at the moment. AFAIK you can only update properties of a few blocks.

Comment: Oh. Well that's unfortunate.